# How to hyperlink the youtube video on button while developing an android app?

Tags: java, android

I am developing an android app and in that i want to hyperlink the youtube video by button so that when i click that button a particular url will open which i provide to it. I want to build many buttons so also tell how to hyperlink a button with another button.
Help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You can set an `onClickListener` on your button which will start the `Intent`:

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {

       Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://google.com/"));
       startActivity(i);

    }
 });
```